# Использование DISTINCT в access 2016

Tags: sql, база-данных, access

Мне нужно подправить этот запрос с учетом двух задач.

1. Найти количество уникальных значений по полю Просители.[Код просителя]
2. Найти по полю Просители.[Код просителя] тех, кто встречается только один или два раза.

```
SELECT Просители.[Код просителя], [Фамилия]+' '+[Просители]![Имя]+' '+[Отчество] AS ФИО, Просители.Архив, Просители.[Не ходит], Просители.[Помощь преостановлена], Дети.Имя, Дети.Дата
FROM Просители INNER JOIN Дети ON Просители.[Код просителя] = Дети.[Код родителей]
GROUP BY Просители.[Код просителя], [Фамилия]+' '+[Просители]![Имя]+' '+[Отчество], Просители.Архив, Просители.[Не ходит], Просители.[Помощь преостановлена], Дети.Имя, Дети.Дата
HAVING (((Просители.Архив)=False) AND ((Просители.[Не ходит])=False) AND ((Просители.[Помощь преостановлена])=False) AND ((Дети.Дата) Is Not Null And (Дети.Дата)>=#1/1/2020#));
```

Answer (score 0):

Это лёгкая задача. Следующий код выведет вам уникальных [Код просителя], а так же сколько раз каждый встречается.

```
SELECT Просители.[Код просителя], COUNT(Просители.[Код просителя])
FROM Просители
GROUP BY Просители.[Код просителя]
```

Для второго вопроса нужно добавить

```
HAVING COUNT(Просители.[Код просителя])=1 OR COUNT(Просители.[Код просителя])=2
```

Если это нужно применить к результатам вашего запроса, тогда включите ваш запрос подзапросом вместо `Просители`

```
...
FROM (ваш запрос)
...
```

В вашем запросе вывод полей `Просители.Архив, Просители.[Не ходит], Просители.[Помощь преостановлена]` не имеет смысла, так как вы делаете отбор по определённому значению этих полей. Поэтому их нужно убрать из вывода и из группировки.

Comment: Как успехи в решении?